# How to reference to specific element in array by its index

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose we have, for instance:

```
const array = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

In case I do this:

```
for(const el of array) console.log(array.indexOf(el))
```

I will always get either 0 or 1 because it will search for the first occurrence that matches the value. How do I refer to the element within an array precisely by its index? That is, how to get "0, 1, 2, 3, 4" in that case? Or even with a more than one dimension array, for example.

Comment: You can just run a regular for loop over it and have access to the index which then you can use to reference the array element `array[index]`

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and print the index

```
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  array[i] === 1 && console.log(i); 
}
```